# What does msm means in android source?

Tags: android, acronym

What does msm means in android source?

there you go. simplest question ever. but no google result for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Not first hit anymore](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/qualcomm/msm). Mobile Station Modem

Comment: So, i can see a lot of msm on the kernel source. that was the reason i asked this question. But what does it stand for?

Comment: @gcb: "Mobile Station Modem", just like it says on Qualcomm's website.